# System memory usage increase after using GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu, pytorch

When I use pytorch/tensorflow to build my neural network, I find that system memory usage increase when I use GPU.

The example code is pretty simple using pytorch, a small Conv1d neural network.

When I set use_gpu=False, the system memory usage is just 131M, . But when I set use_gpu=True, system memory usage increases to more than 2G.

As far as I know, when using gpu, many parameters will be pinned into GPU'S memory, that means the system memory usage will decrease.

Could anyone help to explain the situation ?

Comment: How are you obtaining those memory usage values? Are you sure they don't include allocated GPU memory too? Does your GPU have 2GB memory by any chance?

Comment: Pasting links to images on your hard drive obvious doesn't work. I have removed those links from your question